# Using xslt choose and format-number together

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to bound an integer within a certain range and output it in a decimal format.  I realize it will always be .0 and any modern language should be able to easily cast an integer to a float.  But I've been tasked to do this regardless.

A sample input would look something like the following

---

```
<data guid="25abab12-cb0a-5f37-8a11-121be3a74959">
    <cork_id value="123456" valid="false"/>
    <name> David Moe </name>
    <is_bro>false</is_bro>
    <some_test_value> 200012000 </some_test_value>
    <standard_room_type> liquid </standard_room_type>    
    <environment> Groovy </environment>
</data >
<data guid="f5abab12-cb0a-5f37-8a11-121be3a74959">
    <cork_id value="123456" valid="false"/>
    <name> David Moe </name>
    <is_bro>false</is_bro>
    <some_test_value> 3 </some_test_value>
    <standard_room_type> liquid </standard_room_type>    
    <environment> Groovy </environment>
</data>
<data guid="a5abab12-cb0a-5f37-8a11-121be3a74959">
    <cork_id value="123456" valid="false"/>
    <name> David Moe </name>
    <is_bro>false</is_bro>
    <some_test_value> 250 </some_test_value>
    <standard_room_type> liquid </standard_room_type>    
    <environment> Groovy </environment>
</data >
```

The expected output would copy the above xml but change the some_test_value element to be within the range 5 and 100 and add a .0 to the end to make it a floating point type.
For example,

```
<some_test_value> 200012000 </some_test_value>
```

would become

```
<some_test_value> 500.0 </some_test_value>
```

and
     3

would become

```
<some_test_value> 5.0 </some_test_value>
```

and finally
     250

would become

```
<some_test_value> 250.0 </some_test_value>
```

My incorrect attempt at the xslt would look like the following

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<!--  This is the copy identity -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match ="//some_test_value/text()">
     <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="//some_test_value/text()[. &gt; 500 ]">
     500.0
     </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="//some_test_value/text()[. &lt; 5 ]">
         5.0
       </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:value-of select='format-number(".","#.0")'/>
     </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I cannot follow the logic of your required conversion. I thought I was with you when you **scaled**  200012000 (the max. value?) to 100,  and 3  (the min. value?) to 5 - but then 250 to 250? And your XSLT **clips** at 500 - that's just too confusing.

Comment: @michael.hor257k  Sorry,  that was a typo.   I corrected the post.  Basically,  200012000 would become 500.0 and 3 would become 5.0 and 250 would become 250.0  Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="some_test_value">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=". &lt; 5">5.0</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test=". > 500">500.0</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '#.0')"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is really close to what I'm looking for.  What would I need to include to keep the element tags?  Right now it just outputs the answer without the tag some_test_value.

Comment: Actually,  if I just add /text() to the template match attribute it works the way I need it too.  Can you change it in your answer?  I'll mark it correct.

Comment: @ThomasLann Sorry, I forgot to wrap this in  `<xsl:copy>`. Fixed now.